# Twilio message price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

From what I've seen on the twilio docs, one can actually get the price of the sent message, once it has been properly sent.
However, I can't seem to manage to get it right, perhaps my understanding of the issue is flawed.
I thought perhaps I could add an additional parameter to the status callback sending me also the price, in addition to the other information. Is there a smarter way of doing this? Or am I even on the right track?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Update: I can actually just fetch the message I have sent using the SID from the callback, but the price I get from that is always 0.

Comment: Trying waiting ~2+ hrs to see if the pricing is available when fetching the message SID from the /Messages resource.

Comment: @Alan thank you. I've actually contacted Twilio support and they're aware of their delay issues, ranging from 30 seconds to 2 days :)